# How to apply link_to for only part of the text that's within a content_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the following to display:

```
Long Description(Edit)
```

Only Edit would need the link_to applied to it.

I have the following:

```
 def long_description_title_with_edit_link
  content_tag :th  do
   'Long Description (' + link_to('Edit', edit_product_path(@product), id: 'edit-long-description')+')'
  end
end
```

The link is actually removed when I do it this way. I've tried several variations of:

```
def long_description_title_with_edit_link
 content_tag :th  do
   link_to('Long Description(Edit)', edit_product_path(@product), id: 'edit-long-description')
 end
end
```

This works but makes Long Description and the parenthesis into the link. How do I target only the word Edit?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [concat](https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/) when outputting content of your tag:

```
def long_description_title_with_edit_link
  content_tag :th do
    concat 'Long Description ('
    concat link_to('Edit', edit_product_path(@product), id: 'edit-long-description')
    concat ')'
  end
end
```